# IPN is not received anymore

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have a problem with my IPN sandbox PayPal.  A few days ago it sent the ipn after a test-purchase but since a few days ago it doesn’t sent them anymore. What can I do to fix that error?

signals.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import CourierPayment
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(valid_ipn_received)
def payment_notification(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn = sender
    if ipn.payment_status == 'Completed':
        # payment was successful
        payment = get_object_or_404(CourierPayment, id=ipn.invoice)

        if payment.price == ipn.mc_gross:
            # mark the order as paid
            payment.paid = True
            payment.save()
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CourierConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'courier'

    def ready(self):
        # import signal handlers
        import courier.signals
```

**init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'courier.apps.CourierConfig'
```

Comment: Is an IPN notify_url configured? Where is it configured?

Are IPNs sent? See the history at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: path('paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')), Its configured in main urls.py

Comment: History is present in the sandbox.paypal.

Comment: If the history is present and showing a 200 OK response, then you need to debug your IPN listener. Log what it receives, for starters.

Comment: please guide me how?

Comment: Add code that outputs whatever is received to a file. Then, debug further down.